# Azure Put Blob API returns with a non-matching size of file in canonicalized Header

Tags: python-3.x, rest, azure

I am trying to upload a blob (pdf) file from my laptop to a container in Azure storage account. I found it to be working but with one glitch.

I am calculating the file size using:

```
f_info = os.stat(file_path)          
file_size = (f_info.st_size)          # returns - 19337
```

Then I insert this value in below canonicalized header:

```
ch = "PUT\n\n\n"+str(file_size)+"\n\napplication/pdf\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob" + "\nx-ms-date:" + date + "\nx-ms-version:" + version + "\n"
```

and send the PUT request to PUT Blob API, however, it returns an error saying, "Authentication failed because the server used below below string to calculate the signature"

\'PUT\n\n\n**19497**\n\napplication/pdf\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:[date]\nx-ms-version:[API version]

Looking at this string it obvious that authentication failed because file size which azure calculated returns a different value! I don't understand how its calculating this value of file size?!?!

FYI: If I replace **19337** with **19497** in canonicalized string and re run. It works!
Any suggestion on where I am making mistakes?

### Below is the code:

```
storage_AccountName = '<storage account name>'  
storage_ContainerName = "<container_name>"
storageKey='<key>'  

fd = "C:\\<path>\\<to>\\<file_to_upload>.pdf"

URI = 'https://' + storageAccountName + '.blob.core.windows.net/<storage_ContainerName >/<blob_file_name.pdf>
version = '2017-07-29'                                                                                         
date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT") 

if os.path.isfile(fd):
    file_info = os.stat(fd)
    file_size = (file_info.st_size)

ch = "PUT\n\n\n"+str(file_size)+"\n\napplication/pdf\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob" + "\nx-ms-date:" + date + "\nx-ms-version:" + version + "\n"
cr = "/<storage_AccountName>/<storage_Containername>/<blob_file_name.pdf>"
canonicalizedString = ch + cr

storage_account_key = base64.b64decode(storageKey)
byte_canonicalizedString=canonicalizedString.encode('utf-8')
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(key=storage_account_key, msg=byte_canonicalizedString,  digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())

header = {
          'x-ms-blob-type': "BlockBlob",   
          'x-ms-date': date,
          'x-ms-version': version,
          'Authorization': 'SharedKey ' + storageAccountName + ':' + signature.decode('utf-8'),
          #'Content-Length': str(19497),          # works
          'Content-Length': str(file_size),       # doesn't work
          'Content-Type': "application/pdf"} 


files = {'file': open(fd, 'rb')}
result = requests.put(url = URI, headers = header, files = files) 
print (result.content)
```

Comment: Can you try with `os.path.getsize(file_path)`?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, tried that as well,  both results the same value i.e. 19337

Comment: Can you share the complete code?

Comment: Below is the code:

Comment: Where below? Request you to edit your question and include complete code there.

Comment: Just added in the question section. Comments section won't allow me to..

Comment: Not worked much with Python, but I think the issue is that you're not uploading the file contents. Instead you're uploading an object which contains the file contents and hence the content length is increasing. Can you change the following lines of code: `files = {'file': open(fd, 'rb')}
result = requests.put(url = URI, headers = header, files = files)` with something like: `data = open(fd, 'rb') as stream
result = requests.put(url = URI, headers = header, data = data)`. HTH.

Comment: Other question I have is why you're not using Python's SDK for Azure Storage and going with REST API instead?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thanks that helped.

Comment: Awesome! Let me add that as an answer. Hopefully it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the reason you're getting the content length mismatched header is because instead of uploading the file, you're uploading an object which contains file contents and that is causing the content length to increase.

Please change the following line of codes:

```
files = {'file': open(fd, 'rb')}
result = requests.put(url = URI, headers = header, files = files)
```

to something like:

```
data = open(fd, 'rb') as stream 
result = requests.put(url = URI, headers = header, data = data)
```

And now you're only uploading the file contents.